# Laravel 5.5 facade not found when using alias

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vimeo, laravel-5.5

I created a facade.

```
<?php

namespace VimeoServer\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use VimeoServer\App\Repositories\Contracts\VimeoServerRepository;

class Vimeo extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return VimeoServerRepository::class;
    }
}
```

I registered it inside service provider.

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/../config/vimeo.php' => config_path('vimeo.php'),
        ]);
    }

    $this->app->singleton(VimeoServerRepository::class, function () {
        /*
         * Config.
         */
        $config = config('vimeo.connection');

        /*
         * Repository.
         */
        $repository = new ConcreteVimeoServerRepository($config);

        return $repository;
    });
}
```

I registered the service provider:

```
 VimeoServer\App\Providers\VimeoServerServiceProvider::class
```

and the alias :

```
 'Vimeo' => VimeoServer\Facades\Vimeo::class
```

I am trying to use it inside Video controller.

If I add `use VimeoServer\Facades\Vimeo` in the controller everything works as expected.

The problem appears when I try to use the `\Vimeo` alias, the facade class could not be found.

```
 "message": "Class 'VimeoServer\\Facades\\Vimeo' not found"
```

Comment: composer dump-autoload

Comment: I tried composer dump-autoload / php artisan config:clear. The problem persists. It works if I add the path to the facade but the alias does not.

Comment: i'm not shure about what ar u doing here, but inside the method of ur facede u need to return the string name of ur class not. in ur case  "VimeoServerRepository"

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih that might be the case since aliases are tied to that  static function ! However If you could try in your controller  \Vimeo instead since facades they do live in global dir

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih they are returning the the IoC binding they want to use, `VimeoServerRepository::class` will be the FQCN